# I run Jmeter script from login to the loading dashboard which I recorded from BlazeMeter and I run it,,

Tags: testing, automated-tests, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

The view in the table report is generated in which there is an "Average" and "Deviation" so please explain these terms also ratio.
also what should the average and what should the Deviation for good performace. and how we can calculate.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xeg5.png)

I want to know how to analyze this report as a performance tester

Answer (score 0):

- `Average` is the average response time, basically [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of all response times (their sum divided by their count)
- `Deviation` is the [statistical measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), the higher number you get the higher distribution of response times you get. If you run 2 requests with the same response time - it will be 0, the higher is the difference the higher value you will get

Analyze of "this report as a performance tester" is nearly impossible, you can only check average response times against [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement).

You can try at least generating a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which provides more tables and charts, hopefully you will be able to get more information from there (but your test plan should be designed accordingly in terms of [ramp-up time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) and duration) and correlate increasing load with other performance test metrics like response time, throughput, number of errors, etc.

More information: [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

Comment: the result is  ........ Average =731  and Deviation= 1551  ,  So I want to it is bad or good as a performance point of view